# Numba does not understand vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numba

I have just started working with numba to speed-up my numerical numerical simulations. In the simulation, I have to carry out the vectorization of a 2x2 matrix, however this cannot be done using only numpy methods. See a very minimal example below:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

def example(matrix):
    return matrix.T.reshape((4,1))

matrix = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

example(matrix)
```

This gives my expected outcome, the vectorized form of my matrix:

```
array([[1],
       [3],
       [2],
       [4]])
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with the help of 'jit', I get the following:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def example(matrix):
    return matrix.T.reshape((4,1))

example(matrix)

NotImplementedError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b23f267f5d22> in <module>
----> 1 example(matrix)

NotImplementedError: incompatible shape for array
```

I am very confused by this output as I used only numpy and the documentation of numba states that it supports both '.T' and '.reshape'. A small caveat is that my matrices store numpy.complex128 values, but I get the same error for this minimal code as well.

Comment: This isn't 'vectorization' in the usual 'speedup' sense.  But why use numba for this?  This is efficient numpy already.

Comment: I think that this is what we call vectorization, see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). I want to make it work because I have a function which includes this vectorization method and I want to use it with @jit.

Comment: The link says `flatten` is the numpy form of that definition.  Or the equivalent reshape.  But the most 'natural' reshape in numpy is to (n,) not (n,1), and doesn't reorder terms as your attempt does.

Comment: Actually I need a column vector and not a row vector. Numpy's flatten makes a row vector.

Comment: `flatten` makes a 1d array, which is neither a row vector or column one (though with broadcasting it is functionally close to a row vector). But do you really need the reordering of elements?  `np.ravel()[:,None]` will make a column vector.   With order 'F' the array is more like MATLAB column major matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `copy` makes it work.  In `numpy` reshape after transpose produces a copy, not a view, since the underlying data-buffer is reordered.  Apparently `numba` hasn't added this flexibility to `reshape`.

```
In [161]: @numba.njit
     ...: def foo(arr):
     ...:     return arr.T.copy().reshape(-1,1)
In [162]: 
In [162]: foo(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2))
Out[162]: 
array([[0],
       [2],
       [1],
       [3]])
In [163]: timeit foo(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2))
3.52 µs ± 31.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comparing this to the regular `numpy` version:

```
In [164]: np.arange(4).reshape(2,2).T.reshape(-1,1)
Out[164]: 
array([[0],
       [2],
       [1],
       [3]])
In [165]: timeit np.arange(4).reshape(2,2).T.reshape(-1,1)
3.18 µs ± 15.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

While this action makes a MATLAB style column vector, it's not what we usually call numpy vectorization.  [164] already makes optimal use of numpy compiled methods.